# Can't install Plantuml-mode -- MELPA Package list Incomplete (Mac)

Tags: package, package-repositories, install

I'm trying to install plantuml-mode based on the instructions here:

https://github.com/skuro/plantuml-mode

I'm told to try the following:

```
M-x package-install<RET>
plantuml-mode<RET>
```

But the package isn't found:

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

However, it is listed here on MELPA:

https://melpa.org/#/plantuml-mode

I don't have much experience installing things in Emacs.  Is there some fool-proof way to get this installed on my mac, possibly with a 'recipe'?

I do have plantuml installed.

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with MELPA or plantuml-mode: it has to do with ELPA and the gnu archive. Have you tried eliminating that from `package-archives`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the secure https connection doesn't work. Restart emacs and launch with

`emacs --insecure`

Comment: I doubt that's a good idea. Would you do that in your browser?

Comment: To make https connection always work, add this to your config.el file: ``` '(gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone faces the same problem, my problem was resolved after

- I found in *Messages* that emacs melpa was

  - trying to download from  http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/plantuml-mode-20161225.1142.el where as
  - the the el file I found on melpa site was http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/plantuml-mode-20170819.1033.el .
- Hence I refreshed the contents of packages by running M-x package-refresh-contents .
- then download the jar file from plantuml site.
  voila problem solved